# Dynamically allocate memory, error in copy constructor

Tags: c++, memory, constructor, copy

I have homework to use dynamically allocated memory.  My Professor gave me some instructions. Using them, I coded the below code. I am getting an error at random times.  Some times the error appears before copy execution. Some times it will copy one object and wont copy the next one. I don`t understand what I am doing wrong.

Default constructor

```
GroceryItem::GroceryItem()
{
    item_name = new char[strlen("") + 1];
    strcpy(item_name, "");
    item_price = 0;
    qty_on_hand = 0;
    qty_purchased = 0;
};
```

Function below is copy constructor that I use to copy two objects:

```
GroceryItem::GroceryItem(const GroceryItem& Grocery_in)
{
    item_name = new char[strlen(Grocery_in.item_name) + 1];
    strcpy(item_name, Grocery_in.item_name);
    item_price = Grocery_in.item_price;
    qty_on_hand = Grocery_in.qty_on_hand;
    qty_purchased = Grocery_in.qty_purchased;
}
;
```

below is assigment opperator

```
GroceryItem& GroceryItem::operator=(GroceryItem& copy_item)
{
    if (this == &copy_item)
        return *this;
    else
    {
        delete[] item_name;
        item_name = new char[strlen(copy_item.item_name)+1];
        strcpy(item_name, copy_item.item_name);
        item_price = copy_item.item_price;
        qty_on_hand = copy_item.qty_on_hand;
        qty_purchased = copy_item.qty_purchased;
        return *this ;      // They are the same
    }
}
```

Calls out from function below when I try to copy to temp2:

```
void sort_items(GroceryItem ini_customer_GroceryItem[], int number)
{
    int j = 0, k = 0;
    GroceryItem temp2;

    for (j = 0; j < number - 1; j++)    // n-1 passes
    {
        for (k = number - 1; j < k; k--)    // each pass runs one fewer than the preceding one
        {
            if (ini_customer_GroceryItem[k - 1] > ini_customer_GroceryItem[k])
            {
                temp2 = ini_customer_GroceryItem[k - 1];
                ini_customer_GroceryItem[k - 1] = ini_customer_GroceryItem[k];
                ini_customer_GroceryItem[k] = temp2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error

[image]

Comment: Your professor is doing you a disservice by instructing you to write obsolete C code with strcpy() and strlen(), instead of spending time teaching you real C++ code, like `std::string`, that doesn't need any of this nonsense. You're not being taught the necessary skills that you need to learn in order to become a skilled C++ developer. P.S. I see nothing wrong with the copy constructor. Most likely the memory corruption occurs elsewhere. Just because your code crashed in one particular place, namely the copy constructor, doesn't mean that's where the bug is. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: That's not a copy constructor, it's an assignment operator, and it should take its argument by const reference..

Comment: "Function below is copy constructor" - actually it is assignment operator. Where is your copy constructor?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion i did not include one. i update my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sort_items()` function should use the [`std::swap()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) algorithm instead of copying objects manually:

```
/*
temp2 = ini_customer_GroceryItem[k - 1];
ini_customer_GroceryItem[k - 1] = ini_customer_GroceryItem[k];
ini_customer_GroceryItem[k] = temp2;
*/
std::swap(ini_customer_GroceryItem[k - 1], ini_customer_GroceryItem[k]);
```

Either way, you did not implement a **copy constructor**, only a **copy assignment operator** (and `copy_item` should be `const` in your implementation). See [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). You need to implement a proper copy constructor:

```
GroceryItem::GroceryItem(const GroceryItem& source_item)
{
    item_name = new char[strlen(source_item.item_name)+1];
    strcpy(item_name, source_item.item_name);
    item_price = source_item.item_price;
    qty_on_hand = source_item.qty_on_hand;
    qty_purchased = source_item.qty_purchased;
}
```

And then you can implement your copy assignment operator using the copy constructor:

```
GroceryItem& GroceryItem::operator=(const GroceryItem& copy_item)
{
    if (this != &copy_item)
    {
        GroceryItem temp(copy_item);
        std::swap(temp, *this);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
GroceryItem& GroceryItem::operator=(GroceryItem copy_item)
{
    std::swap(copy_item, *this);
    return *this;
}
```

And, of course, don't forget a destructor, if you have not already implemented one:

```
GroceryItem::~GroceryItem()
{
    delete[] item_name;
}
```

And an `operator>()`, of course, since `sort_items()` expects one.

Now, with that all said, if you change the `item_name` member to be a `std::string` instead of a `char*`, you won't need to manually implement a destructor, copy constructor, or copy assignment operator at all (just the default constructor to zero-initialize the numeric members).  The compiler's default generated implementations for the destructor, copy constructor, and copy assignment operator will suffice for managing all of the data members for you:

```
class GroceryItem
{
public:
    std::string item_name;
    float item_price;
    int qty_on_hand;
    int qty_purchased;

    GroceryItem();

    bool operator > (const GroceryItem& item) const;
};

GroceryItem::GroceryItem()
{
    item_price = 0.0f;
    qty_on_hand = 0;
    qty_purchased = 0;
};

bool GroceryItem::operator > (const GroceryItem& item) const
{
    return ...;
}

void sort_items(GroceryItem ini_customer_GroceryItem[], int number)
{
    int j = 0, k = 0;
    //GroceryItem temp2;

    for (j = 0; j < number - 1; j++)    // n-1 passes
    {
        for (k = number - 1; j < k; k--)    // each pass runs one fewer than the preceding one
        {
            if (ini_customer_GroceryItem[k - 1] > ini_customer_GroceryItem[k])
            {
                /*
                temp2 = ini_customer_GroceryItem[k - 1];
                ini_customer_GroceryItem[k - 1] = ini_customer_GroceryItem[k];
                ini_customer_GroceryItem[k] = temp2;
                */
                std::swap(ini_customer_GroceryItem[k - 1], ini_customer_GroceryItem[k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Than for all you comments, i`ll change my code and see if it`s work.

Comment: Found some issue with code for char, 

`GroceryItem& GroceryItem::operator=(const GroceryItem& copy_item)

    {
    if (this != &copy_item)
    {
        GroceryItem temp(copy_item);
        std::swap(temp, *this);
    }
    return *this;
    }`

Comment: What issue are you seeing?

Comment: It loops in that return this field. basically it stay In loop between swap and return this. I actually end up using 5 rule for construction opperator with move function and etc. I have me less random errors, but still they happens.

Comment: There is nothing I have shown that should be causing an endless loop inside of `swap()`, or after it. The only looping is inside of `sort_items()`.